# how to exit from a function but not from main()

Tags: c++, c, function

Does C/C++ support terminating a program from a subroutine function i.e not main?
So far I only found that exit and abort allow a user to terminate current function or process.
If I'm not in main function, is there a way to terminate the whole program?

Comment: You've answered your own question.

Comment: You can call `exit` from any function, not just from `main`.

Comment: I have the opposite problem. I'm exiting a function and it exits the program, which I do not want. It's a `void` function so I  cannot return. How can I exit w/o killing the program? Like return in other languages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not in `main()` and in other function then also you can call `exit()` or `abort()` it will terminate your whole process.

where `exit()` will do required clean up where `abort()` will not perform that.

Answer (score 1):

```
exit(0) or exit(1)
```

If this is `0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, it indicates success.
If it is `EXIT_FAILURE`, it indicates failure.

ref: [See here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/)

Comment: And `exit(1)` may indicate either success or failure -- better to stick to the standard values.

Answer (score 1):

since you're talking C++, consider **[`std::terminate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/terminate/)**

u now, for “Does C/C++ support terminating a program from a subroutine function i.e not main?”

by default `std::terminate` calls `abort`, but this is configurable by installing a handler via `std::set_terminate`

Answer (score 0):

void exit (int status)

Above method Terminates the process normally, performing the regular cleanup for terminating programs.

Normal program termination performs the following (in the same order):

1. Objects associated with the current thread with thread storage duration are destroyed (C++11 only).
2. Objects with static storage duration are destroyed (C++) and functions registered with atexit are called.
3. All C streams (open with functions in ) are closed (and flushed, if buffered), and all files created with tmpfile are removed.

And after that Control is returned to the host environment.

As it terminates the calling process, becuase your function is part of same process, so  using exit() in that will terminate the program.

Comment: you may use status Status code.
 If this is 0 or EXIT_SUCCESS, it indicates success.
 If it is EXIT_FAILURE, it indicates failure.

Answer (score -2):

It can only be possible if you called that function from main function. And from that function from which you want to terminate the program return a value for terminating the program for example -1.

Example:

```
void main()
{
    //Call to a function
    int i = functionFromMain();
    if(i == -1)
    {
        //Terminate Program
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not exactly the answer to the question. exit() or abort() for the function itself will cause the whole function to terminate.

Comment: -1 `void main` has never been standard, neither in C nor in C++